# Java Swing Program not re-initialinzing variable value

Tags: java, swing

I have made a simple java swing program using eclipse,But there is a problem; the code only works correctly when the calculate button is pressed for the first time, After first time it malfunctions.I dont know why, I have tried to find the problem but couldn't find the problem.
Here is the code :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;


public class Cgpa extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textFieldGpa1;
private JTextField textFieldGpa2;
private JTextField textFieldGpa3;
private JTextField textFieldGpa4;
private JTextField textFieldGpa5;
private JTextField textFieldGpa6;
private JTextField textFieldGpa7;
private JTextField textFieldGpa8;
private JTextField textFieldcr1;
private JTextField textFieldcr2;
private JTextField textFieldcr3;
private JTextField textFieldcr4;
private JTextField textFieldcr5;
private JTextField textFieldcr6;
private JTextField textFieldcr7;
private JTextField textFieldcr8;
private JLabel lblSemesterSgpa;
private JLabel lblSemesterSgpa_1;
private JLabel lblSemesterSgpa_2;
private JLabel lblSemesterSgpa_3;
private JLabel lblSemesterSgpa_4;
private JLabel lblSemesterSgpa_5;
private JLabel lblSemesterSgpa_6;
private JLabel lblSemesterSgpa_7;
private JLabel lblSemesterCredit;
private JLabel lblSemesterCredit_1;
private JLabel lblSemesterCredit_2;
private JLabel lblSemesterCredit_3;
private JLabel lblSemesterCredit_4;
private JLabel lblSemesterCredit_5;
private JLabel lblSemesterCredit_6;
private JLabel lblSemesterCredit_7;
private JButton btnNewButton;


double creditHoursTotalDegree=0;
String CGPA;
double temp =0;
String sgpaInput[] = new String[8];
String crHrInput[]  = new String[8];

double Sgpa[] = new double[8];
double crHr[]  = new double[8];
private JTextArea textArea;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Cgpa frame = new Cgpa();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Cgpa() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 580, 357);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    textFieldGpa1 = new JTextField();
    textFieldGpa1.setColumns(10);

    textFieldGpa2 = new JTextField();
    textFieldGpa2.setColumns(10);

    textFieldGpa3 = new JTextField();
    textFieldGpa3.setColumns(10);

    textFieldGpa4 = new JTextField();
    textFieldGpa4.setColumns(10);

    textFieldGpa5 = new JTextField();
    textFieldGpa5.setColumns(10);

    textFieldGpa6 = new JTextField();
    textFieldGpa6.setColumns(10);

    textFieldGpa7 = new JTextField();
    textFieldGpa7.setColumns(10);

    textFieldGpa8 = new JTextField();
    textFieldGpa8.setColumns(10);

    textFieldcr1 = new JTextField();
    textFieldcr1.setColumns(10);

    textFieldcr2 = new JTextField();
    textFieldcr2.setColumns(10);

    textFieldcr3 = new JTextField();
    textFieldcr3.setColumns(10);

    textFieldcr4 = new JTextField();
    textFieldcr4.setColumns(10);

    textFieldcr5 = new JTextField();
    textFieldcr5.setColumns(10);

    textFieldcr6 = new JTextField();
    textFieldcr6.setColumns(10);

    textFieldcr7 = new JTextField();
    textFieldcr7.setColumns(10);

    textFieldcr8 = new JTextField();
    textFieldcr8.setColumns(10);

    lblSemesterSgpa = new JLabel("Semester 1 SGpa");

    lblSemesterSgpa_1 = new JLabel("Semester 2 SGpa");

    lblSemesterSgpa_2 = new JLabel("Semester 3 SGpa");

    lblSemesterSgpa_3 = new JLabel("Semester 4 SGpa");

    lblSemesterSgpa_4 = new JLabel("Semester 5 SGpa");

    lblSemesterSgpa_5 = new JLabel("Semester 6 SGpa");

    lblSemesterSgpa_6 = new JLabel("Semester 7 SGpa");

    lblSemesterSgpa_7 = new JLabel("Semester 8 SGpa");

    lblSemesterCredit = new JLabel("Semester 1 Credit Hours");

    lblSemesterCredit_1 = new JLabel("Semester 2 Credit Hours");

    lblSemesterCredit_2 = new JLabel("Semester 3 Credit Hours");

    lblSemesterCredit_3 = new JLabel("Semester 4 Credit Hours");

    lblSemesterCredit_4 = new JLabel("Semester 5 Credit Hours");

    lblSemesterCredit_5 = new JLabel("Semester 6 Credit Hours");

    lblSemesterCredit_6 = new JLabel("Semester 7 Credit Hours");

    lblSemesterCredit_7 = new JLabel("Semester 8 Credit Hours");

    btnNewButton = new JButton("Calculate CGpa");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            temp=0;
            for(int i=0; i<8 ; i++)
            {
                Sgpa[i] = 0;
                crHr[i] = 0;

            }

            sgpaInput[0] = textFieldGpa1.getText(); 
            sgpaInput[1] = textFieldGpa2.getText(); 
            if(textFieldGpa3.getText().equals(""))
            {
                sgpaInput[2] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                sgpaInput[2] = textFieldGpa3.getText();
            }
            if(textFieldGpa4.getText().equals(""))
            {
                sgpaInput[3] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                sgpaInput[3] = textFieldGpa4.getText();
            }
            if(textFieldGpa5.getText().equals(""))
            {
                sgpaInput[4] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                sgpaInput[4] = textFieldGpa5.getText();
            }
            if(textFieldGpa6.getText().equals(""))
            {
                sgpaInput[5] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                sgpaInput[5] = textFieldGpa6.getText();
            }

            if(textFieldGpa7.getText().equals(""))
            {
                sgpaInput[6] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                sgpaInput[6] = textFieldGpa7.getText();
            }
            if(textFieldGpa8.getText().equals(""))
            {
                sgpaInput[7] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                sgpaInput[7] = textFieldGpa8.getText();
            }


            crHrInput[0] = textFieldcr1.getText();
            crHrInput[1] = textFieldcr2.getText();
            if(textFieldcr3.getText().equals(""))
            {
                crHrInput[2] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                crHrInput[2] = textFieldcr3.getText();
            }
            if(textFieldcr4.getText().equals(""))
            {
                crHrInput[3] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                crHrInput[3] = textFieldcr4.getText();
            }
            if(textFieldcr5.getText().equals(""))
            {
                crHrInput[4] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                crHrInput[4] = textFieldcr5.getText();
            }
            if(textFieldcr6.getText().equals(""))
            {
                crHrInput[5] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                crHrInput[5] = textFieldcr6.getText();
            }
            if(textFieldcr7.getText().equals(""))
            {
                crHrInput[6] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                crHrInput[6] = textFieldcr7.getText();
            }
            if(textFieldcr8.getText().equals(""))
            {
                crHrInput[7] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                crHrInput[7] = textFieldcr8.getText();
            }

            Sgpa[0] = Double.parseDouble(sgpaInput[0]);
            Sgpa[1] = Double.parseDouble(sgpaInput[1]);
            Sgpa[2] = Double.parseDouble(sgpaInput[2]);
            Sgpa[3] = Double.parseDouble(sgpaInput[3]);
            Sgpa[4] = Double.parseDouble(sgpaInput[4]);
            Sgpa[5] = Double.parseDouble(sgpaInput[5]);
            Sgpa[6] = Double.parseDouble(sgpaInput[6]);
            Sgpa[7] = Double.parseDouble(sgpaInput[7]);

            crHr[0] = Double.parseDouble(crHrInput[0]);
            crHr[1] = Double.parseDouble(crHrInput[1]);
            crHr[2] = Double.parseDouble(crHrInput[2]);
            crHr[3] = Double.parseDouble(crHrInput[3]);
            crHr[4] = Double.parseDouble(crHrInput[4]);
            crHr[5] = Double.parseDouble(crHrInput[5]);
            crHr[6] = Double.parseDouble(crHrInput[6]);
            crHr[7] = Double.parseDouble(crHrInput[7]);



            for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
            {
                creditHoursTotalDegree=creditHoursTotalDegree +crHr[j];
                //System.out.println(Sgpa[j]);
                //System.out.println(crHr[j]);

                temp = temp + (Sgpa[j] * crHr[j]);
                //System.out.println(temp);                                         
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,SGPA);
            }
            temp = temp/creditHoursTotalDegree;

            CGPA =String.valueOf(temp);
            textArea.setText(CGPA);


        }

    }


    );

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
    gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
        gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_7)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_6)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_5)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_4)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_3)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_2)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_1)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa))
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(textFieldGpa8)
                            .addComponent(textFieldGpa7)
                            .addComponent(textFieldGpa6)
                            .addComponent(textFieldGpa5)
                            .addComponent(textFieldGpa4)
                            .addComponent(textFieldGpa3)
                            .addComponent(textFieldGpa2)
                            .addComponent(textFieldGpa1))
                        .addGap(31)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_1)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_2)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_3)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_4)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_5)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_6)
                            .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_7))
                        .addGap(5)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(textFieldcr3)
                            .addComponent(textFieldcr2, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 91, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textFieldcr4, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 96, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textFieldcr5, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 96, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textFieldcr6, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 96, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textFieldcr7, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 96, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textFieldcr8, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 96, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textFieldcr1)))
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(131)
                        .addComponent(btnNewButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 248, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(28)
                        .addComponent(textArea, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 495, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
    );
    gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
        gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(3)
                        .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit))
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(textFieldGpa1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(textFieldGpa2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_1))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(textFieldGpa3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_2))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(textFieldGpa4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_3))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(textFieldGpa5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_4))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(textFieldGpa6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_5))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(textFieldGpa7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_6))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(textFieldGpa8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterSgpa_7)))
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(textFieldcr1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(textFieldcr2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_1))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_2)
                                .addComponent(textFieldcr3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_3)
                                .addComponent(textFieldcr4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_4)
                                .addComponent(textFieldcr5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_5)
                                .addComponent(textFieldcr6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_6)
                                .addComponent(textFieldcr7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblSemesterCredit_7)
                                .addComponent(textFieldcr8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnNewButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(textArea, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
    setVisible(true);
}

}
```

All the calculation is being performed in temp variable, and it's been re-initialized every time the button is clicked, but its not working. Please help as its very frustrating.

Comment: can you reduce your code to post only relevant part?

Comment: You really should use arrays and loops.

Comment: Please don't post a massive wall of code like this. As @BhavikShah asked, [a Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/) would make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: cut down your code to only the necessary code that explains the problem

Comment: When you post a question, you need to say more than "it's not working." What's not working? What results do you expect? What results are you getting? Be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't post anything like this next time. just the needed part.
your problem is that you refresh `temp = 0` on every call of `actionPerformed`, but you forget to reset `creditHoursTotalDegree = 0`. It accumulates on every call.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to reinitialize `creditHoursTotalDegree`.